# How to ignore a PC which is shut down or locked or not connected with the network?

Tags: bash, shell

I have defined an array of strings (Names of PCs). The script will copy `File 1` from a remote PC and save it locally. The grep command will read the `File 1` and save the results in another file. But when a PC is shut down or not connected with the network, the script will not execute and I have to press <kbd>Ctrl+C</kbd> and then it will move to next PC.

How I can change this script so that whenever a PC is shut down or not connected with the network or is locked it moves to the next PC? For example when `user2@PC2` is shut down or not connected with the network or locked (required password), the script should automatically move to `user3@PC3`. It should copy `File1` from each online `user@PC` once and then run grep.

```
#!/bin/sh

word=name

declare -a arr=("user1@PC1" "user2@PC2" "user3@PC3")
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
    for t in 1 2 3
    do
        scp ${i}:/PCpath/File1 ./File${t}
        grep -e "${word}" "File${t}" >| /home/new/File${t}`_$(date`)
    done
done
```

Comment: `scp` should time out if it can't connect to the server.

Comment: You can try pinging the remote machine first, and skip it if it doesn't respond.

Comment: @Barmar thanks but how i can change the above script to skip if a pc does not respond?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `ping` to test if the remote PC is up before trying to copy from it.

```
    for i in "${arr[@]}"
    do
        if ping -q -c 2 "$i"
        then
            for t in 1 2 3
            do
                scp ${i}:/PCpath/File1 ./File${t}
                grep -e "${word}" "File${t}" >| /home/new/File${t}`_$(date`)
            done
        else
            echo "$i down, skipping"
        fi
    done
```